# How to get the id resource id of a view in a List view

Tags: android, listview

I have `Listview` which is showing different images of animals,birds,reptiles. The list view is working fine. Now I want when user click to any picture it should appear in the `ImageView`.The `ImageView` is just below the `listview`. so when ever user will click any image in the `listview` it should appear in the `Imageview`.

Also there is a button. Now I want to achieve that when user select any image and press Ok button that paticular image should show on the image view of other activity also. I Know I can send the Id through `intent.putextra()`, but the problem is first place how to get the id of particular picture.

Source code

```
public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

private TypedArray ListIcons;
private HorizontalListView listView;
private ArrayList<AnimalsListItems> SuitItems;
private  AnimalsListAdapter adapter1 = null;

/** An array of strings to populate dropdown list */
String[] actions = new String[] {
        "Bookmark",
        "Subscribe",
        "Share"
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
    listView = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.suits_list);
    AnimalsItems = new ArrayList<AnimalsListItems>();
    /** Create an array adapter to populate dropdownlist */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);


    /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
    ;
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("    "+"            "+"     ");

    /** Defining Navigation listener */
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected : " + actions[itemPosition], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            ListIcons = getResources()
                    .obtainTypedArray(R.array.ic_launcher);// load icons from
            // strings.xml
            for (int i = 0; i<=ListIcons.length(); i++) {

                AnimalsItems.add(new AnimalsListItems(ListIcons.getResourceId(i,-1)));
            }
            adapter1 = new SuitsListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),SuitItems);
            Log.v(adapter1.getCount()+"");
            listView.setAdapter(adapter1);

            return false;
        }
    };

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //With the position parameter, you can fetch the item at the clicked position like below. Cast it to whatever type your ListView is.
     Object yourItem = (Object) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
         //Now you can assign the image to an imageview
                      }
           });

            /** Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar */
            getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);

    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left,
            R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
}
```

}

Comment: kindly show ur effort . what the result you get from google by searching ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `ListView`, you can set an `onItemClickListener` as below

```
ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //With the position parameter, you can fetch the item at the clicked position like below. 
        AnimalsListItems yourItem = (AnimalsListItems) listView1.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //Now you can assign the image to an imageview 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what do you mean by Object , ? and then how to set the image in the imageview  in thi onitmeclickListenere. my imageview name is imanimal;

Comment: Why on earth do you cast the item to an Object? Most pointless upcast ever. :)

Comment: @ JHH it was my fault not of Marcus

Comment: Fair enough. I did bother to read your entire answer though. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "id", if you're talking about drawable id's, path to image files, or just any way to identify your image. It depends a lot on how you populate your list. You didn't supply any code at all.

But since you have a ListView I suppose you have an Adapter, and that you're backing that adapter with some data, such as an array, database etc. When you click on an item, you get an onItemClick callback with the index of the item you clicked on. You should be able to use this index to find which image you clicked on from your data source.

Then when it comes to passing that to *another* activity, well, again it depends on how you represent your images but you should be able to pass whatever data you need to represent the image in an intent extra to the second activity.

Comment: yes you guesed well , I have arrayAdapter and i have setting images in that way . and Yes i want the drawable image name. for example, if the user has clicked on the elephant and the picture is saved in drawable with the name of elephantblue.png , so in this case I want to get the name of this picture (I am saying it as a Id)

Comment: So, given that, what exactly is your issue? Could you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: onItemClick() gets the position of the item. You have the array of items (AnimalsItems). Use the position to get the item from the array...

(BTW does your strings come from an array called ic_launcher???)

Comment: yes it comes from the array named ic_launcher, which is saved in the strings .xmls

Comment: and please tell me how to use the poistion to get the id of that image which is clicked

Comment: You have an array. You have the position. Do you seriously want me to give you the code for getting an item from an array at a given position?
My comment about ic_launcher was just because it's a very confusing name, considering it's the default name for your application icon. It makes no sense to use that symbol name for an array of animals. It does not affect the function of your program though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setOnItemClickListener method of ListView to get witch item clicked.Because one item one image, you can get the target image.

Answer (score 0):

1.Step

Rather getting resource id you can create one integer array containing resource id's like,

int resourceID[] = [R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ...]

Assign this array to your ListView image item

2.Step

Now can easily get the postion of selected list item or image using Lists on item click method

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {} )

3.Step
Just pass your ResourceID array & tapped position to next/target activity & use it, rather passing resourceID

or

Otherwise make your ResourceID as static, pass only tapped position to next Activity & use this static ResourceID from previous Activity

i.e -> yourImageView.setImageResource(FirstActivity.ResourceID[position])

Comment: this seems easy but I am getting error when I sets this 
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, resourceID);

it says can not apllied int to int[]

Comment: No don't do in such way.. you want only ArrrayAdapter..? can you use BaseAdapter..?

Comment: Yes I can use BaseAdapter